# 【Rails】How can I write child directory path in route.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The code is below.

```
#app/controllers/admin/feeds_controller.rb

class Admin::FeedsController < ApplicationController
def api_index
```

```
#routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/hoge' do
    resource :feeds, only: [] do
      collection do
        get :api_index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My wish is that path is `hoge/feeds/api_index` and can execute `api_index` action in `admin/feeds_controller`.

The `routes.rb` is currently Routing Error.

Because the path is `controller/feeds`.

How can I call `api_index` action in `controller/admin/feeds`?


Thank you.

## Error(Add)

I wrote the below

```
#routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/hoge' do
    resource :feeds, controller: 'admin/feeds',  only: [] do
      collection do
        get :api_index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, I got a error

```
undefined local variable or method `api_index' for Admin::FeedsController:Class
```

But I definitely　wrote `def api_index` in `app/controllers/admin/feeds_controller.rb`

How Can I do that?

Comment: You can specify the `controller` option, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!
I got it!!
But I got a other error....
I edited my question.
How can I do that..?

Comment: I'm so sorry.
I solved the error.thank you!

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer, so the question can get closed and maybe it can help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `namespace`.
More info in the Rails guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

```
#app/controllers/admin/feeds_controller.rb

class Admin::FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def api_index
  end
end
```

```
#routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    scope '/hoge' do
      resource :feeds, only: [] do
        collection do
          get :api_index
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```